# Is it possible to export a branded an Swing Eclipse OSGi Application

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I have some bundles, that are independent of SWT and eclipse framework.

I would like to use the Eclipse RCP just to export the equinox framework. Starting equinox, I would like to show the splash screen (just if it is easy and possible) and after, the equinox start my main bundle.

Is it possible and easy? I can't found documentation.

I've followed the equinox documentation to autoload the bundles but it doesn't worked.

http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/documents/quickstart-framework.php

Comment: If all you want to use is equinox, why do you want to "use the Eclipse RCP"?

Comment: Because I like splashes and branding of eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse RCP is independent of SWT.  If you want to use RCP for this, then in the start method of your IApplication, simply perform whatever tasks you want, which could include launching swing.

Also note that Equinox is independent of RCP.  You could also choose to bring up the Equinox OSGi environment entirely without resorting to RCP if you so desire.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using just equinox. Thanks for you answer.